# failing to include the path in php.ini

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include this path to the zend framework, but failing:

```
include_path = ".;C:\ZendFramework-1.11.11\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library"
```

should the Zendframework reside in a different folder?

UPDATE
It works now.. I typed zf show version.

I want to set the thing to as an environmental variable, which means that no matter from where I will type the command in the command line... zf show version will work..

I went to to the environment variables by clicking the right button on my computer, and then navigating to Environment variable and setting the path like this.

zf show version

variable name: Temp
variable path: %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp;C:\xampp\php;

Basically, I want to set C:\xampp\php as a default so that I wont need to navigate to the directory each time i start the command line

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the include path?

Comment: create a new file in your document folder then use `<?php phpinfo();` as the code in it. See 1) where the php.ini file is it wants to use and 2 what the include_path is defined as there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Zendframework doesn't have to reside in a different folder.
Your include_path is right and should has worked.
Is it that your path Zend library path is not right?
what is the error your got?

Comment: I am trying to execute this: export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/zend/framework/bin/directory
   and it tells that export is not a command

Comment: export is a shell command, it does not have much to with PHP. So your real problem is that you can not execute the command above?

Comment: true..but i think it is interconnected.  ..how do I set path..?

Comment: considering your include_path setting, you should be using a windows box. while `export` is a shell command under linux(it's right to set path in linux like above).  As for windows, you'd right click your computer icon, select 'property', then 'Advanced' tab, and click 'environmental variables'